# How to mount a drive on startup in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I have a disk partition that is mapped to a separate volume which is listed as

```
/dev/sda3/ /media/DATA fuseblk ...
```

in gnome-system-monitor when mounted. However when I start Ubuntu it is not mounted and `cd /media/DATA fails`. I usually need to firtst access the drive through Nautilus. How do I make it availabale on startup?

Answer (score 7):

The partition must be mounted before you can access it.
You need to add the volume /dev/sda3 to /etc/fstab.

for example:

```
 file system    mount point       type          options

 /dev/sda3      /media/DATA       vfat            ...
```

Follow this article:

[Ubuntu - Mount Partitions Automatically](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions)